# Passing value to <input> using handlebars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, ejs

In EJS, we use this syntax to pass a value to an input field and prevent it from resetting if form validation has failed.

```html
<input
  type="name"
  id="name"
  name="name"
  placeholder="Enter Name"
  value="<%= typeof name != 'undefined' ? name : '' %>"/>
```

My concern here is with the value parameter. What would be handlebars alternative to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

For just this cause you can do it like this

```
<input
  type="name"
  id="name"
  name="name"
  placeholder="Enter Name"
  value="{{#if name}}{{name}}{{/if}}"/>
```

If you specifically want to match the type & other expressions, then you'll have to write custom helper function for the same

See the reference : https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#custom-helpers